# Continuously differentiable operator

Tags: analysis, derivatives, differential-operators, greens-function

I consider an operator $A:H^1_0\to H^1_0$ defined by $$Au(t)=\int_0^1 G(t,s) f(s,u(s))ds$$ where $$ G(t,s)=\begin{cases} t(1-s), &t\leq s\\s(1-t), &s\leq t.\end{cases}$$

I want to know what can be the condition on $f$ to obtain that $A$ is continuously differentiable?

Can I do this: 
$$
\begin{align}
A'(u)[v](t) &=\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{A(u+hv)(t)-Au(t)}{h} \\
&=\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\int_0^1 G(t,s) \frac{f(s,(u+hv)(s))-f(s,u(s))}{h} ds\\
&=\int_0^1G(t,s) f_{u}(s,u(s)) v(s) ds ?
\end{align}
$$

So the condition on $f$ is to be continuously differentiable. Is it right ?

Thank you

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by continuously differentiable. Do you mean that the operator is differentiable or that its range consists of continuously differentiable functions?

Comment: We need that $A'u$ continuous, because i have a functional $J$ such that $J''(u)=Id-A'(u)$ so to obtain that $J''$ is continuous we need that $A'$ continuous

Comment: The derivative must be $f_u(s, u(s)) v(s)$ where $f_u$ is the partial derivative of $f$ with respect to the second argument $u$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is true.

As not specified clearly, from the context I infer and assume 
$$ H^1_0 = H^1_0[0,1] = \{ f\in L^2[0,1] \mid \text{the weak derivative} f'\in L^2[0,1], f(0)=f(1)=0 \}. $$
The key idea is, that $H^1_0$ is continuously embedded in $C[0,1]$, 
as for $u\in H^1_0$ we have
$$  |u(x)| \le \int_0^x |u'(t)| \mathrm d t \le \sqrt{\int_0^1 |u'(t)|^2 \mathrm d t} \le \|u'\|_{L^2} \le \|u\|_{H^1_0}. $$

**As $f$ is $C^1$, the limit of the differential quotient exists and takes that value.**

*Proof:*
Notice that $G$ is bounded by $1$. Further, for $0 < |h| \le 1$ we have
$$ 
\begin{align}
\left|\frac{f(s, (u+hv)(s)) - f(s, u(s))}{h}\right| 
&=  \frac1{|h|}\left|\int_{u(s)}^{u(s)+hv(s)} f_u(s, \mu) \mathrm d \mu \right| \\
&=  \frac1{|h|} \left|\int_{0}^{h} f_u(s, u(s)+\eta v(s)) v(s) \mathrm d \eta \right| \\
&\le \frac1{|h|} \int_{0}^{h} |f_u(s, u(s)+\eta v(s))| |v(s)| \mathrm d \eta \\
&\le M_v \|v\|_{\infty}
\end{align}
$$ 
with
$$ M_v = \sup\{ |f_u(s, u(s)+\eta v(s))| : 0\le s, \eta\le 1 \}, $$
which is finite, as $f_u, u, v$ are continuous and $u,v$ are bounded.
Thus, the dominated convergence theorem applies.

**The operator $A'(u)$ is linearly bounded.**

*Proof*:
As $f_u(s, u(s))$ is uniformly bounded for $0\le s\le 1$ with the same argument before, 
it follows
$$ \|A'(u)[v]\|_{L^2}^2 
\le \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \left| G(t,s) f_u(s,u(s)) v(s) \right|^2 \mathrm d s \mathrm d t
\le M_0^2 \int_0^1 |v(s)|^2 \mathrm d s
\le M_0^2 \|v\|_{H^1_0}^2.
$$
As $G$ is Lipschitz contiuous with $\|G_t\|_\infty \le 1$, we have
$$ (A'(u)[v])'(t) = \int_0^1 G_t(t,s) f_u(s, u(s)) v(s) \mathrm d s $$
with
$$ \|(A'(u)[v])'\|_{L^2}^2 
\le \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \left| G_t(t,s) f_u(s,u(s)) v(s) \right|^2 \mathrm d s \mathrm d t
\le M_0^2 \int_0^1 |v(s)|^2 \mathrm d s
\le M_0^2 \|v\|_{H^1_0}^2.
$$
That is $A'(u)$ is a linearly bounded operator from $H^1_0$ to $H^1_0$.

**Finally, $A'$ is continuous at $u$.**

*Proof:* Fix $u\in H^1_0$. Let 
$$ U = \overline{\{ \tilde u(s) : \| \tilde u - u \|_{H^1_0} \le 1 , 0\le s\le 1 \}}, $$
which is bounded and closed, thus compact.
Then, $f'$ is uniformly continuous on $[0,1]\times U$.

Let $\epsilon > 0$. Then, there exists some $\eta > 0$ such that for every $(s_1,\mu_1),(s_2,\mu_2)\in[0,1]\times U$ with $\|(s_1,\mu_1)-(s_2,\mu_2)\| < \eta$ it follows
$$ |f_u(s_1, \mu_1) - f_u(s_2, \mu_2)| < \epsilon.$$
Now, for this $\eta$ there exists some $\delta > 0$ such that for every $u,\tilde u\in H^1_0$ with $\| u - \tilde u\|_{H^1_0} < \delta$ it follows $\| u - \tilde u\|_\infty < \eta$.
Thus, for this $\delta$ and every $\tilde u$ in the $\delta$-neighborhood of $u$, we have 
$$ |f_u(s, u(s)) - f_u(s, \tilde u(s))| < \epsilon $$
for every $0\le s\le 1$. 
Then, dominated convergence theorem yields the continuity of $A'$ at $u$.

Comment: Please to introduce the limite under the integral we need to have that $G(t,s) \frac{f(s,(u+hv)(s))-f(s,u(s))}{h}$ is dominated by an $L^1$ function ?

Comment: @Vrouvrou I add the complete proof. It would also work for the codomain $L^2$. However, I am not sure about $H^1_0$.

Comment: A is from $H^1_0$ to $H^1_0$

Comment: @Vrouvrou, it will work, as $G_t$ is bounded. You only need to change the $A'(u)$ is bounded and $A'$ is continuous part, to include the norm of $(A'(u)[v])'$.

Comment: I don't understand :"You only need to change the $A′(u)$ is bounded part"

Comment: @Vrouvrou: 1) You need to show that $A'(u)$ is bounded operator from $H^1_0$ into now $H^1_0$, that is $\| A'(u)[v] \|_{H^1_0} \le C \| v \|_{H^1_0}$ for some $C\in\mathbb R$ independent of $v$. My proof was formulated for the codomain $L^1$. However, you can adapt it easily to $H^1_0$. 2) Also the proof for the continuity of $A'$ can be easily adapted, as the argument is still the same.

Comment: why A'u must be bounded ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25492/discussion-between-user251257-and-vrouvrou).